# How to use the Remote Desktop's internet connection from my machine?

Tags: windows, internet, remote-desktop

I can connect to a remote desktop using the Remote Desktop Connection. Everything works fine and the remote desktop can access the Internet. I can also pass files back and forth with the remote machine.

Is it possible to tunnel the Internet connection of the remote machine to my machine, so I could use my browser, for instance, and not the remote's?